# ODE in variable $r$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm sure this is a simple question but I will need help.

While trying to solve a PDE using separation of variables I came across an ODE.

I want to solve the following  ODE:
$$\frac{R''(r)+\frac{2}{r}R'(r)}{R(r)}=-\lambda^2$$

The solution is $A\cos(\lambda r)/r +B\sin(\lambda r)/2\lambda r$

It checks out when you plug it in but how do we actually get the solution?

Comment: Note that the solution is simply : $$R(r)=A\cos(\lambda r)/r +B\sin(\lambda r)/r$$ Since $B, \lambda,2$ are just constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{R''(r)+\frac{2}{r}R'(r)}{R(r)}=-\lambda^2$$
$$r{R''(r)+{2}R'(r)}=-rR(r)\lambda^2$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(rR(r))''=-rR(r)\lambda^2$$
$$(rR(r))''+rR(r)\lambda^2=0$$
Now just solve it as :
$$y''+\lambda^2y=0$$
Where $y=rR(r)$. It's just a second order linear differential equation that is easy to solve.

Comment: thanks. going from your second to third line, how do you account for the 2R' term?

Comment: Differentiate $rR$ gives us $(rR)'=R+rR'$ differentiate again ..$.(rR)''=2R'+rR''$ @jana I hope it's more clear now Jana